# MKMapView circular swift

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit

Gostaria de saber se tem como deixar o MKMapView no Xcode com formato circular. Tentei usar o mapView.layer.cornerRadius, porém mesmo assim não consegui

Comment: Você importou o QuartzCore.h (`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`)? Sem isso o `cornerRadius` não vai ter efeito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz aqui um teste e vi que usando cornerRadius funciona normalmente.

**1.**  Adicionar o `QuarzCore.framework` no projeto indo em Build Phases > Link binary with libraries.

1.1
[image: Build Phases]

1.2
[image: Link Binary With Libraries]

**2.** Importar `QuartzCore` no seu projeto

**Swift:**

```
import QuartzCore;
```

**Objective-C:**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

**3.** Usar a propriedade `corerRadius` do layer da view.

```
// cornerRadius com metade da altura de uma view quadrada deixa ela redonda
// neste caso uma view de 290x290
mapView.layer.cornerRadius = 145;
```

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado está funcionando agora, foi mais erro de matemática mesmo. Tinha que ser um quadrado e o raio metade do quadrado.